# How to open GWT CellTree nodes by clicking on text not icon

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using `GWT CellTree` complex example as discribed in [javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTree.html). But to open tree node I must click on little arrow on the left of the node. I want to open tree by clicking on text. I searched some help and found out that I can use `ClickableTextCell`. Truly said, I don't understand where to start. Can you help me or provide another solutions? I want that node look like an anchor: when I mouse on the text, cursor become pointer and text is underline.

```
public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
      if (value == null) {
        ListDataProvider<Composer> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<CellTreeExample2.Composer>(
            composers);
        Cell<Composer> cell = new AbstractCell<Composer>() {
          @Override
          public void render(Context context, Composer value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            if (value != null) {
              sb.appendEscaped(value.getName());
            }
          }
        };
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<Composer>(dataProvider, cell);
      } else if (value instanceof Composer) {
        ListDataProvider<Playlist> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<Playlist>(
            ((Composer) value).getPlaylists());
        Cell<Playlist> cell = new AbstractCell<Playlist>() {
          @Override
          public void render(Context context, Playlist value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
            if (value != null) {
              sb.appendEscaped(value.getName());
            }
          }
        };
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<Playlist>(dataProvider, cell);
      } else if (value instanceof Playlist) {
        ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>(
            ((Playlist) value).getSongs());
        return new DefaultNodeInfo<String>(dataProvider, new TextCell(),
            selectionModel, null);
      }

      return null;
    }
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
      if (value instanceof String) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use a Cell for catch the click on the cell (like ClickableTextCell).
In my project, I implemented this sytem for just first levels of an Tree :

```
Cell<String> nodeCell = new AbstractCell<String>("click", "keydown") {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element parent, String value, NativeEvent event, ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater) {
        String eventType = event.getType();
        // Special case the ENTER key for a unified user experience.
        if ("click".equals(eventType) || ("keydown".equals(eventType) && event.getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER)) {
            tree.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(context.getIndex(), !tree.getRootTreeNode().isChildOpen(context.getIndex()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        if (value != null) {
            sb.appendEscaped(value);
        }
    }
};
```

For open more levels, you must use setChildOpen in cascade :

```
tree.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(1, true).setChildOpen(1, true).setChildOpen(1, true);
```

Comment: I can't override onBrowserEvent method, it is an error. I can only add  @SuppressWarnings("unused"), so this method is never used. Only arrow keys works on my keyboard and open/close nodes.

Comment: params in your onBrowserEvent depends to your `AbstractCell<T>` : `void onBrowserEvent(Context, Element, T, NativeEvent, ValueUpdater<T>)`

Answer (score 1):

Because you probably don't want those nodes to also be selectable, I'd use a `NoSelectionModel`.

Whenever you click on those nodes, call `setChildOpen()` on the parent `TreeNode` to toggle its state. To get the parent `TreeNode`, use `setChildOpen(index, true)` on the grandparent `TreeNode` (recursively up to `getRootTreeNode()`: because you know the node has already been loaded and is open (you're responding to an event on a child node), you can be sure that `setChildOpen` will return the `TreeNode` rather than `null`.
Finally, to get the `index` to pass to the `setChildOpen` methods, just use an `indexOf()` on the parent "domain object"'s list of children (i.e. `composers.indexOf(composer)`, `composer.getPlaylists().indexOf(playlist)`, etc.). This assumes that you can easily get the *parent* of a given object (the composer of a given playlist), either by maintaining bidirectional relations (`playlist.getComposer().getPlaylists().indexOf(playlist)`), or by building a map of the child→parent relations.

Below are some building-blocks that you'd call from the `NoSelectionModel`'s `SelectionHandler`:

```
void toggleComposerOpen(Composer composer) {
  int index = composers.indexOf(composer);
  TreeNode rootTreeNode = tree.getRootTreeNode();
  rootTreeNode.setChildOpen(index, !rootTreeNode.isChildOpen(index));
}

void togglePlaylistOpen(Playlist playlist) {
  Composer composer = playlist.getComposer();
  TreeNode composerTreeNode = getTreeNode(composer);
  int index = composer.getPlaylist().indexOf(playlist);
  composer.setChildOpen(index, !composer.isChildOpen(index));
}

private void TreeNode getTreeNode(Composer composer) {
  int index = composers.indexOf(composer);
  return tree.getRootTreeNode().setChildOpen(index, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Rough Idea

Use a `SingleSelectionModel` and pass it into your `DefaultNodeInfo`. Add an `onSelectionChanged` handler, such that when it is called:

1. Get the selected item
2. Find the index of the item in the associated `ListDataProvider`, this will be used to open the associated child index
3. Use the `CellTree` root `TreeNode` to open the associated child index
4. Clear the selection model so that when the item is selected again (consecutively), the `onSelectionChanged` event will be fire again. This will emulate toggling.

## Example: `addSelectionChangeHandler`

Add selection change handler.

```
composerSingleSelectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Composer>(COMPOSER_KEY_PROVIDER);
// ...
composerSingleSelectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(
    new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
            final TreeNode rootTreeNode = cellTree.getRootTreeNode();
            final Composer selectedComposer = composerSingleSelectionModel.getSelectedObject();
            if (selectedComposer == null) return;
            final int index = composerListDataProvider.getList().indexOf(selectedComposer);
            if (index < 0) return;
            final boolean isOpen = rootTreeNode.isChildOpen(index);
            rootTreeNode.setChildOpen(index, !isOpen);
            /* Clear what is currently selected, so that
            * onSelectionChange is fired again when the same item is
            * selected consecutively.
            */
            composerSingleSelectionModel.clear();
        }
    });
```

## Example: Custom `TreeViewModel`

Pass in composer selection model to custom `TreeViewModel`.

```
public class MusicTreeViewModel implements TreeViewModel {
    // Define constructor to pass in properties ...

    @Override
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return new DefaultNodeInfo<Composer>(composerListDataProvider, composerCell, composerSelectionModel, null);
        } else if (value instanceof Composer) {
            final Composer composer = (Composer) value;
            final Object composerKey = composerListDataProvider.getKey(composer);
            final ListDataProvider<Playlist> playlistListDataProvider = getPlaylistListDataProvider(composerKey);
            return new DefaultNodeInfo<Playlist>(playlistListDataProvider, playlistCell, playlistSelectionModel, null);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Unsupported object type: " + value.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Composer) {
            return ((Composer) value).getPlaylists().isEmpty();
        } else if (value instanceof Playlist) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```